# Is there a way to prevent iTunes from renaming TV Show filenames?

Tags: itunes, finder, video

I have imported quite a few TV Shows into iTunes and I have noticed that iTunes renames the files in the style *Episode number Episode name.m4v* (e.g. 01 - My First Day.m4v).

This is not a useful way of naming the files as if the show has multiple seasons you can't order the files in Finder by season as you could if it was in the format *Season number Episode number Episode name.m4v* (e.g. S01E01 My First Day.m4v).

When files are imported or if the filename is changed myself in Finder, iTunes renames the file back to its format.

Is there a way to prevent iTunes from renaming these files?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want iTunes to manage your files at all then go to:
`iTunes > Preferences > Advanced`, and uncheck the `Keep iTunes Media Folder Organised` checkbox.

Alternatively, iTunes uses each item's Title to rename the file, so if you edit the info of a file within iTunes (`CMD + I`) you can set the title to something to your liking such as `<show name> <season no.><episode no.>` e.g. `Silicon Valley S03E01`.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, stop using iTunes.  Use a separate video program to watch the files and store them in your own folders.